# SimpleCV not working in PYCharm

Tags: pycharm, simplecv

I installed the superpack of SimpleCV and PyCharm. I then install the package from PyCharm for SimpleCV, and it's successful. But when I run the sample program from the official website and I get the following message:

```
ImportError: Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV
```

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have figured it out.

After the superpack of SimpleCV installation is done, open the command prompt and enter the following:

```
SETX PATH C:/Python27/;C:/Python27/Scripts/;C:/<DIR>/build/x86/vc10/bin/;%PATH%
SETX PYTHONPATH C:/<DIR>/opencv/build/python/2.7/;%PYTHONPATH%
```

Change the drive letter and DIR to the path where SimpleCV is installed on your system (Most probably C:/SimpleCV1.3/files/).

Close the command prompt and launch PyCharm and go to settings(Ctrl+Alt+S) and navigate to ***Project Interpreter*** and on the right pane, click the ***green add button***.

[image: PyCharm - Project Interpreter]

Then search for SimpleCV and install the package as shown:

[image: Package Installation]

Close PyCharm and download SimpleCV1.3 from [GitHub](https://github.com/sightmachine/simplecv) and copy the ***sampleimages*** folder to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\`

Try the following sample code, and it should work fine.

```
from SimpleCV import Camera
# Initialize the camera
cam = Camera()
# Loop to continuously get images
while True:
    # Get Image from camera
    img = cam.getImage()
    # Make image black and white
    img = img.binarize()
    # Draw the text "Hello World" on image
    img.drawText("Hello World!")
    # Show the image
    img.show()
```

Hope this helps!!